# SNEEZY Error on Encryption - Email Message Relation Object

Tags: encryption, shield

Similar to another question I posted [regarding a SLEEPY error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284602/sleepy-error-on-encryption), now we have encountered a SNEEZY error. We are trying to enable the Encryption Policy for the Email Message Relation field to "Deterministic - Case Insensitive". This works in Sandbox, but not in Production.

Does anyone have info on the Email Message / Relation field in regards to encryption?

**Some Notes:**

1. Salesforce support says we've reached our Custom Field Limit of 800.They also recommended emptying the recycle bin in case there were deleted fields hiding in there.
2. When you use "Deterministic - Case Insensitive" as an encryption method Salesforce creates a hidden field that translates the original field into lowercase. Per Salesforce, this is where the problem is - we're at our 800 field limit and can't create a new field.
3. In the previously reported question, Salesforce Tier 3 support was able to set the field to "Deterministic - Case Insensitive" encryption on our behalf, but they were unable to do so this time.
4. I am able to change the Encryption to "Probabilistic" and "Deterministic -Case Sensitive" without issue. It is only with the "Insensitive" option where there is trouble.
5. However, as a follow up test, I updated Opportunity > Next Steps field to "Deterministic - Case Insensitive" encryption without issue.
6. This leads me to believe the issue is specifically with the Email Message Relation field/record itself and not with the custom field limit Support has suggested.

EDIT: Here's a link to the Known Issue logged with SFDC: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ePwQAI

Comment: Here is the related issue referenced above: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284602/sleepy-error-on-encryption

Comment: Dwarf error resolution is generally going to be guesswork by anyone not within Salesforce Support, FYI. Those internal errors aren't intended for public consumption and interpretation.

Comment: Totally understood, but the answers given by SFDC Support didn't feel accurate and further testing seemed to validate that there are other reasons. Hopefully the next info from them solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Per Support, this has been reported as a bug (not handling the raw error code properly).

They should have replied to you as follows:

> Case-insensitive deterministic encryption requires two custom fields; you have exceeded the custom field limit on object EmailMessageRelation which is ZERO as EmailMessageRelation is non-customizable.

The `800` was a red herring as it would only apply to objects like Lead, Contact, Account, etc. where hitting the 800 limit is plausible.

Comment: Of note, you can still encrypt with the Probabalistic and Deterministic - Case Sensitive options. It's only the Insensitive encryption option that is a problem (due to the above).

Comment: Additionally, the restriction on Case Insensitive encryption is only in place in Production orgs, in Sandbox you can use Deterministic - Case Insensitive as an option without issue. Lastly, the Email Relation Message object is not currently in the Metadata API, so you can't deploy using change sets or deployment applications (like Gearset), like you can for other objects.

Comment: We have asked SFDC Support to hide the Case Insensitive option as it is not valid in Production.